# Creating a loop that outputs an extra space for each line

Tags: python

For example

```
Hello World
 Hello World
  Hello World
   Hello World
```

I have tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(""*i, "Hello World")
```

Comment: So what happens instead? "doesn't work" is not a very good problem description.

Comment: Try putting a space inside the quotation marks

Comment: When you repeat an empty string `n` times you still get an empty string. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
for i in range(4):
    print(' '*i + "Hello World")
```

Use the `+` for string concatenation. This allows your code to work on both python 2 and 3.

The main issue was that you want to concatenate actual spaces `' '` instead of empty strings `''`. Multiplying an empty string by itself many times results in just the empty string itself.

Comment: Or use `sep=''` to remove the space inserted by `print()`.

Comment: OPs main problem was the missing space. `print(" "*i, "Hello World")` would also work given python 3+

Comment: Sure. I should have specified that I use `+` for concatenation so that it works on both python 2 and 3 @castis. A version wasn't tagged for this question so if anyone comes to this question in the future, `+` would work no matter which version they use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for i in range(4):
     print(" "*i, "Hello World")
```

Comment: This will *start* with a single space, and go up to four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It does work if you fix the typo - putting " " instead of "" in print:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(" "*i, "Hello World")
```

Now that adds an extra space at the start even if the first argument of print() is an empty string, so to get the output where the first line has no leading spaces you could use print with a single argument:

```
print(" " * i + "Hello World")
```